# Multi File Codes for Arduino for Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino

I'm using VS Code with an Arduino Mega and I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement a multi-file workflow. So far I have been able to incorporate a header file, however I'm not sure how to get the extension to include the other .cpp files into the build.

Current folder structure:

```
-Workspace
---main
-----main.ino
---src
-----add.cpp
-----add.h
```

So it builds main.ino fine, and includes the header fine, but of course it's not compiling add.cpp. This isn't unexpected, as I haven't told the compiler to include it. For g++ compiling I've always just included the .cpp files as arguments, i.e. "${fileDirname}\*.cpp", in the tasks.json. I can't find any good instructions for how to do similar using the Arduino for VS Code extension. What is the best way to have VS Code build all relevant .cpp files for Arduino?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain and simple by using the free [platformio plugin](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/integration/ide/vscode.html) for vs code. The best solution I found for working with arduino.

This plugin is reliable, platform independent, open source and you can manage projects with header files and the linking and compiling is done by dialogue. Also the documentation is well written.

I hope you have as much fun programming with it as I do :)

Comment: You are welcome :) I now love to write arduino code, sure you will too :)

Comment: PlatformIO did the trick here. Much easier to use, and I was able to put all dependent files into the /src directory, and it built and uploaded without issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The cpp file should habe been compiled but linked if needed. You dont need to tell the compiler to compile that file. Just include the header file in both files: main.cpp and add.cpp.

Your header file must look similar to this

```
#ifndef ADD_H__
#define ADD_H__

//All your code

#endif //ADD_H__
```

This precompiler trick will allow you to include your header anywhere but will prevent the redefinitions.

Comment: You are right, this seems to work for .cpp and .h files that are *in the root project folder* (next to the .ino file). It does no longer work when these additional files are moved to a subfolder like "src" as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a temporary solution to this problem, do not now if it is a good one, in terms of the professional coding guidelines.

Say, we have the following structure:

```
-Workspace
---main
-----main.ino
---src
-----add.cpp
-----add.h
```

then in *main*:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "src/add.h"

void setup(){
    your code here
}

contine the code.
```

then in *add.h*:

```
#ifndef _ADD_H_
#define _ADD_H_

Your code

#include "add.cpp"
#endif
```

and in *add.cpp*:

```
#include "add.h"

your code comes here
```

Then the source code for the library *add* should also get compiled.
I struggled with a simmilar problem, and found this thread. This solution I am proposing works for me, without the use of platform.io (which was not an option for me). But like I said, I do not know if this is according to some professional coding guidelines.